# WPF Position TextBlock/Label on the Line center

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, binding

Im trying to represent weighted graph with MVVM inside canvas
so im representing graphs vertices and edges as observable collections and putting them into canvas ItemsControl. But I cant find any reasonable way to position text that represents weight on the center of line(graphs edge)

my canvas xaml:

```
<Canvas Background="Linen" ClipToBounds="True"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EdgeItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" 
                          X1="{Binding V1.X}" Y1="{Binding V1.Y}"
                          X2="{Binding V2.X}" Y2="{Binding V2.Y}"/>                                                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
```

[What i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx0ec.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `EdgeItem` class (or whatever's in your `EdgeItems` collection).

```
    //  When V1 or V2 changes, raise PropertyChanged("Margin")
    public Thickness Margin => new Thickness(Left, Top, 0, 0);
    public double Left => Math.Min(V1.X, V2.X);
    public double Top => Math.Min(V1.Y, V2.Y);
```

I'm assuming `EdgeItem` has a `Weight` property -- if not, `Weight` is a stand-in for whatever property you want to display in the center of the line. I would have thought `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` would work, but for me they don't in this case.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Line 
                Stroke="Black" 
                StrokeThickness="4" 
                X1="{Binding V1.X}" 
                Y1="{Binding V1.Y}"
                X2="{Binding V2.X}" 
                Y2="{Binding V2.Y}"
                />
            <Label 
                Background="#ccffffff"
                Content="{Binding Weight}" 
                Margin="{Binding Margin}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

## Second Method

Alternatively, don't add the `Margin`, `Left`, and `Top` properties to `EdgeItem`, and generate the margin `Thickness` with a value converter instead. I'm not crazy about having those properties on `EdgeItem`, but then again on the other hand, a value converter on `{Binding}` is a problem with raising `PropertyChanged`, if you happen to alter `V1` or `V2` at runtime. The solution to that would be to make it a multi value converter and bind `V1` and `V2` separately with a multi binding. I just got lazy about writing that XAML.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Line 
                Stroke="Black" 
                StrokeThickness="4" 
                X1="{Binding V1.X}" 
                Y1="{Binding V1.Y}"
                X2="{Binding V2.X}" 
                Y2="{Binding V2.Y}"
                />
            <Label 
                Background="#ccffffff"
                Content="{Binding Weight}" 
                Margin="{Binding Converter={local:EdgeItemMargin}}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Converter:

```
public class EdgeItemMargin : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var edge = (EdgeItem)value;

        return new Thickness(
            Math.Min(edge.V1.X, edge.V2.X), 
            Math.Min(edge.V1.Y, edge.V2.Y), 
            0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: why do you derive EdgeItemMargin form MarkupExtension?

Comment: @HenrikHansen Habit. They can be given named and typed (but not bound) parameters that way, though in this case there's no need for that.